# Modern equivalent of Astronomical Algorithms by Jean Meeus?

Tags: algorithm

I understand that the [Meeus book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0943396611) is a classic in astronomical calculations. I've read through many chapters of it now and while the content is great, it'd be nice to have discussion based on more recent context.

Is there a "modern equivalent" to this classic book?

Comment: If there is one, I would also like to know about it! I think it remains the only work of its kind, though. Updated quantities have been published here and there, but not in a single work. For example, for the Moon’s orbit, one can refer to Éphémérides Lunaires Parisiennes; for the planets, to VSOP 2013; etc.

Comment: The amazon comments seem to have suggestions.. Also observe that the author is long-dead, the work is therefore copyright free and I don't see how amazon can charge 100$ for this.. ridiculous capitalism.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Supply was disrupted when Willmann-Bell went out of business. Sky Publishing now [sells it for $36](https://shopatsky.com/products/astronomical-algorithms-2nd-edition). Copyright endures several decades after publication or author's death depending on country.

Comment: @MikeG Ah, I was under the impression that he is already dead for a century..

Comment: He is still alive. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Meeus *Astronomical Algorithms* was first published in 1991.

Comment: @MikeG That's probably good enough to be converted to an answer, along with the detail that the author is still alive.

Comment: The closest thing to an updated version is the Explanatory Supplement to the Astronomical Almanac, 3rd ed, but it is not aimed at amateurs.

Answer (score 3):

The methods described in Jean Meeus's book are still valid, and accurate enough for the needs of most amateur and many professional astronomers.  The science of positional astronomy doesn't change so rapidly that a book published in 1991 would be out of date only 30 years later.  Even methods developed in the 19th century, such as Besselian elements of eclipses, are still useful in the 21st century.

Having said that, better solar system ephemerides do appear from time to time, such as the newer ones from IMCCE which supersede VSOP87.  In my own code (written in Java and available at GitHub: https://github.com/DavidHarper/astrojava) I prefer to use the JPL Development Ephemeris representations of the orbits of the Moon and planets, because they are computationally easier to use than the IMCCE representations.  However, I don't criticise Meeus (or anyone else) for choosing VSOP87.

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* Are these the "newer ones from IMCCE"? https://www.imcce.fr/services/ephemerides/ If so perhaps you an add this link to your post. *Thanks!*

Comment: random factoid; while [PyEphem and XEphem are based on VSOP87](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34487170/3904031) the newer Python package [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) imports the JPL DE that the user specifies, plus Keplerian orbital elements for minor planets and comets not represented in the DEs.

Comment: Sorry for so many comments; just fyi there are [almost 200 Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) and these include [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/), [retrocomputing SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/).